# PRAWN - Two variables in same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I wish to have a Prawn PDF which will contain a column containing two variables. Here is my table definition:

```
def transactions_table
  grid([3,0], [14,3]).bounding_box do
    data = [%w(Date Description Amount)]
    data += @rows.map{|r| [r.value_date, r.description, r.amount, r.credit]}
    options = { header: true, width: 520, 
        column_widths: {0 => 100, 2 => 200},
        row_colors: ['EEEEEE', 'FFFFFF']}
    table(data, options) do 
      cells.padding      = 5
      cells.border_width = 0.5
      cells.border_color = BLACK

      row(0).font_weight = 'bold'
      row(0).border_color = BLACK

      column(2).align = :right
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see there are four columns `value_date`, `description`, `amount` and `credit`. I want to have `amount` and `credit` in the same column, however, I'm not sure how to do this. Simply removing the comma does not work. Is there a joiner could someone fill me in. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use a hash like this? `@rows.map{|r| [r.value_date, r.description, {amount: r.amount, credit: r.credit}]}`

Comment: Sorry but this didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two values in one string, for example with string interpolation.

```
data += @rows.map{|r|
 [r.value_date, r.description, "#{r.amount} #{r.credit}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That hit the spot.

Answer (score 1):

You can join two strings with the `+` operator. I'm not sure if the values you want to join are strings, but you can make sure they are with the `to_s` method:

```
data += @rows.map{|r| [r.value_date, r.description, r.amount.to_s + ' ' + r.credit.to_s]}
```

Comment: Oh, I see a syntax error: `r.credit_to_s` should be `r.credit.to_s` I'll change it to fix the error, but @Meier has given essentially the same answer as me without the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is was to remove borders:

```
    column(3).borders = [:top, :right, :bottom]
    column(2).borders = [:top, :left, :bottom]
```